# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un elemento a un arreglo usando "add" en c#?

Tags: c#, array

estoy teniendo problemas con almacenar datos de manera estructurada en C#. He leído que para cargar datos en arrays o matrices hay que usar el método "add" pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo hacerlo. ¿Me ayudáis?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Add
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay que diferenciar entre Arrays y List.

Un Array es un conjunto de objetos (o variables simples) con un tamaño fijo. Cuando lo creas le asignas el tamaño  tendrá ese siempre. En los arrays no eite el metodo add.

```
String[] array = new string[10];
array[0] = "Primer valor del array de strings";
array[1] = "Segundo valor";
```

Una lista es un conjunto ilimitado de lo que sea, este contiene el metodo add entre muchos otros.

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Primer valor");
list.Add("segundo");
```

Entonces, ¿cuando usar uno o el otro?

El array es ideal para cuando tienes un numero limitado de valores que siempre van a ser esos, por ejemplo quieres guardar el nombre de a quien le toca lavar los platos cada mes del año. Puedes tener un array de 12 posiciones porque siempre guardaras 12 nombres, nunca mas ni menos.

Las listas sirven para cuando quieres poder modificarlas comodamente. No solo cambiar los valores, si no añadir tantos como quieras, borrar el elemento que desees, moverlos, etc.

En resumen, esta en tus manos cuando usar uno u otro. Uno es mas sencillo, el otro es mas potente.

Comment: +1 _"con un tamaño fijo"_

Comment: @NaCl, Un array tiene el tamaño fijo, no? Es decir desde el principio te crea X referencias a objeto (sean o no null)

Comment: Sí, literalmente puedes hacer un array de tamaño dinámico, pidiendo su tamaño por el teclado, pero no deja de ser fijo, ya que una vez introducido el valor del tamaño del `Array`  se vuelve _fijo_.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma sería usando un List:

```
string valor = "valor1";

 List<string> elementos = new List<string>();
 elementos.Add(valor);
```

Tu List de string puede ser convertido a un array de la siguiente forma:

```
int[] arrayElementos = elementos.ToArray();
```

Es importante establecer la diferencia entre los dos para que puedas definir el uso:

Un [**List**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) (lista), es un conjunto ilimitado de elementos, a los que se puede obtener acceso por medio del índice. Proporciona métodos para buscar, ordenar y manipular listas, entre ellos se encuentra el método [.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx).

En cambio un [**Array**](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/arrays/) es un conjunto de objetos pero con un tamaño finito.